# How to binding different data context to data template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I try to simplify my Main user control that contains 8 user controls that are exactly the same but they are binding to different VM to display its data.
Currently, I have to create a template for each of my user control and binding to each of VM.
It seems that I can create one data template for all 8 user controls and apply the data template to each of the user control with different instance of VM.

Here are my code that current I have to use different templates for different dependency of View Model containing the data of each gauge

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AnalogIO1Template" DataType="{x:Type local:CAnalogIOVM}">
        <local:ucAnalogIO 
            GaugeValueDP="{Binding Path=GaugeValue1VMDP.GaugeValue, ElementName=ucAnalogIOWindow}">
        </local:ucAnalogIO>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="AnalogIO1Template" DataType="{x:Type local:CAnalogIOVM}">
        <local:ucAnalogIO 
            GaugeValueDP="{Binding Path=GaugeValue2VMDP.GaugeValue, ElementName=ucAnalogIOWindow}">
        </local:ucAnalogIO>
    </DataTemplate>

   <Grid Background="#FFE3E2D7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <ContentControl x:Name="ucLinearGauge1">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnalogIO1Template }" />
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="#FFE3E2D7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <ContentControl  x:Name="ucLinearGauge2">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnalogIO2Template }" />
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

Here I try to create one Data template for all 8 user controls but it does not work

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AnalogIOTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:CAnalogIOVM}">
        <local:ucAnalogIO 
            GaugeValueDP="{Binding Path=GaugeValue, ElementName=ucAnalogIOWindow}">
        </local:ucAnalogIO>
    </DataTemplate>
   <Grid Background="#FFE3E2D7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=GaugeValue1VMDP}" x:Name="ucLinearGauge1">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnalogIOTemplate}" />
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

Is there a way to binding different data context to the data template?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean your controls inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`?

Comment: Yes. All of the 8 user controls are inherited from UserControl.  Thanks

Comment: Then, in the first place, it is not necessary to prepare a UserControl for each type of VM as long as VM has properties that are to be bound with those of the UserControl. What is your actual issue?

Comment: These user controls have the same interface (GUI) and have about 8 properties to set. I create it as User Control to be able to reuse to display on different Views. On this view, I got 8 of them.  It all works but I think it would be cleaner if I can set different data context the data template.  The VM is also the same class but with different data for the gauge from 1-8. Thanks

Comment: If the different view-models have the same 8 properties, put those 8 properties either into a common base class or a common interface they implement and bind the `DataTemplate` against that.  e.g.  `<DataTemplate x:Key="AnalogIO1Template" DataType="{x:Type local:IViewModelBase}">`

Comment: How would I specify the instance of VM1-8 to the data template using the common interface? Currently, I already have different instance of VM1-8 for the same class CAnalogIOVM.  Would It make any difference to change to interface? Thanks

Comment: @ThichCoiPhim It sounds like if you just need to set `GaugeValueDP` with each VM's `GaugeValue`, you don't need to use DataTemplate.

Comment: I do get more than 1 on in the VM. I just show 1 for simplicity.  I currently have 8 properties to set. per user control.

Comment: @ThichCoiPhim So the only difference of 8 cases are instance of `CAnalogIOVM`? If so, you can bind each instance with `DataContext` of corresponding `ucAnalogIO`.

Comment: That is what I am binding right now by creating 8 different data templates to bind with different instance of VM.  I prefer to create 1 data template and binding different instance of VM to the data template when it is used in the grid for display user control.  Thanks

Comment: @ThichCoiPhim You might misunderstand what I wrote. I am talking about `DataContext` property of `ucAnalogIO` which inherits from `FrameworkElement` but not other properties like `GaugeValueDP`.

Comment: How do I do that at this View?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If class of `UserControl`, class of VM and bindings between them are identical and the only difference is instances of VM, creating a Style for UserControl and binding each instance of VM with `DataContext` of corresponding instance of UserControl would be enough.

Since we don't know actual code of your `UserControl` and VM, I will show this by samples.

Sample UserControl which has **Id** dependency property and can show its value:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.SampleUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="IdTextBlock"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class SampleUserControl : UserControl
{
    public int Id
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Id", typeof(int), typeof(SampleUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, (d, e) => ((SampleUserControl)d).IdTextBlock.Text = e.NewValue.ToString()));

    public SampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Sample VM which has **Id** property and MainWindow's VM which has instances of sample VM:

```cs
// using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

public class SampleViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public SampleViewModel? VM1 { get; }
    public SampleViewModel? VM2 { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        VM1 = new SampleViewModel { Id = 10 };
        VM2 = new SampleViewModel { Id = 20 };
    }
}
```

Finally, bind each instance of sample VM with `DataContext`  of corresponding instance of sample UserControl so that **Id** of sample VM is bound with **Id** of sample UserControl.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="400" Height="200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SampleUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="Id" Value="{Binding Id}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:SampleUserControl DataContext="{Binding VM1}"/>
        <local:SampleUserControl DataContext="{Binding VM2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample codes. However, I still try to figure how to pass VM to the child user control inside a parent user control.  My main Window contains multiple views which are user control.  One of them has many child user controls which I need to pass VM from MainViewVM to the parent User control.  From that User control, I need to set VM1-8 to each child control.  All works the way I have right now but I have to explicitly to specify the VM inline with the binding as I mentioned from the above.

Comment: I think you can specify parent UserControl by ElementName.